# How to get all data post midnight of different timezone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I have a PostgreSQL table named `testing` with a column named `creation_time` as `timestamp with time zone`. The database timezone is `UTC`

Now I want to get all rows whose time is greater than 00:00 of the current day as per the timezone "America/New_York".

I know how to get all rows after local midnight:

```
SELECT * FROM testing
WHERE  ( creation_time >= now()::date)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But how to use this query with a different timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *"the current day"* is also defined by NY time, not by the current timezone setting.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   testing
WHERE  creation_time >= date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```

Yes, `AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` twice. No typo there.

`now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')` gets local NY time. `date_trunc` gets 00:00 of that day. The 2nd `AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` converts the local time back to `timestamptz`, which we finally compare to.

If you want NY 00:00 of your *local* date, it's simpler:

```sql
WHERE  creation_time >= CURRENT_DATE::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

Same *time*, but can be a different day!

[`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is the local date (date according to the time zone setting of the current session). Effectively the same as `now()::date`.

Further reading:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: what is `current_date`

Comment: thank you, very difficult to know such things

Comment: @Santhosh: I added a bit on `CURRENT_DATE` above.

Comment: `WHERE  creation_time >= CURRENT_DATE::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` -- i didnt understand what will this do

Comment: @Santhosh: Like I said, it computes NY 00:00 of your local date (not of the current NY date, which may be one day ahead or behind).

Comment: also if i want to get all data past few days or week with ` AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'`

Comment: @Santhosh: Sorry, I don't understand. Please start a new *question* for your new question. You can always link to this one for context, and drop a forward link here (to also get my attention).